# how to solve "symbol does not have visible declaration error"

Tags: vhdl

My vhdl code is as follows:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

entity pc is
port( inp : in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
  oup : out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0));
end pc ;

architecture behv of pc is
signal programcounter : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
begin
process(inp)
begin
programcounter<=inp;
oup<=programcounter;
end process;
end behv;

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity ins_memory is
port( inp1 : in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
  oup1 : out std_logic_vector (4 downto 0));

end ins_memory;

architecture behv1 of ins_memory is
type ROM_Array is array (0 to 14)
of std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);
constant Content: ROM_Array := (
0 => "00001",
-- Suppose ROM has
1 => "00010",
-- prestored value
2 => "00011",
-- like this table
3 => "00100",
--
4 => "00101",
--
5 => "00110",
--
6 => "00111",
--
7 => "01000",
--
8 => "01001",
--
9 => "01010",
--
10 => "01011",
--
11 => "01100",
--
12 => "01101",
--
13 => "01110",
--
14 => "01111",
--
OTHERS => "11111"
--
);

component pc is
port( inp : in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
  oup : out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0));
end component ;

begin
D1: pc port map(inp1);
process(inp1)
begin
oup1<= Content (to_integer(inp1));
end process;
end behv1;
```

Here basically, I am trying to instantiate `pc` in entity `ins_memory` which is a ROM

The error I am getting is :

> oup1<= Content (to_integer(inp1));                   The symbol
>   'TO_INTEGER' does not have a visible declaration.

so, How can I solve this error?

Comment: Which tool do you use? Please add a tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two entity/architecture declarations, but only the first uses `std_logic_arith/unsigned` packages, thus these are not known to the second.  So add it before `ins_memory` the entity:

```
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
```

Next, the `to_integer` is from the `numeric_std` package.  The `std_logic_vector` to `integer` convert in the `std_logic_unsigned` package is named `conv_integer`, so update the `oup1` assign to:

```
oup1<= Content (conv_integer(inp1));
```

Btw, you can get ridge of the component declaration if you instantiate the `pc` entity directly with:

```
D1 : entity work.pc port map(inp1);
```

Another btw., consider using the VHDL standard `numeric_std` package instead of the proprietary Synopsys `std_logic_arith/unsigned` packages.

Comment: or simply numeric_std_unsigned (-2008).   The key idea here is that any of these treat a std_logic_vector as an unsigned value, which also points out `use ieee.numeric_std.all; ... oup1 <= Content (to_integer(unsigned(inp1));` which uses numeric_std.to_integer [unsigned return integer] instead of using numeric_std_unsigned.to_integer [std_logic_vector return integer]. So we're standing waist deep in ways to get it to work. (Both of these defined a to_integer).